# Regd. Watermarking on PDF using Overlay on Linux is not working but on windows

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to watermark to a pdf page by using overlay with pdf doc as shown below. This is working fine on windows but not on unix/linux, it is not throwing any error on unix/linux.

```
ResourceLoader resLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
// watermark.pdf is in classpath
InputStream is = resLoader.getResource("watermark.pdf").getInputStream();
byte[] watermarkBytes = new byte[is.available()];
is.read(watermarkBytes);

Overlay overlay = new Overlay();
overlay.setInputPDF(document);
overlay.setOverlayPosition(Overlay.Position.BACKGROUND);
overlay.setAllpagesOverlayPDF(PDDocument.load(watermarkBytes));
overlay.overlay(new HashMap<>(Integer, String));
```

We got the log as below.

### log

```
DEBUG o.a.p.p COSParser missing end of file marker '%%EOF'
DEBUG o.a.p.p COSParser set missing offset 17 for object 1 0 R
DEBUG o.a.p.p COSParser set missing 125 for object 2 0 R.
..
..
.. etc

So primarily i am facing the below two issues on linux/unix. 
1. ResourceLoader.getResource().getFile is not working and throwing filenotfoundexception though the path in debug is correct, so used getinputStream() instead and it is working fine to load the content from specified file path.
2. While passing this byte array as an input to the setAllPagesPDF() it is not throwing any error and watermarking is not happening for the pages a specified. Log above is the cause i could not figure it out why? 

Thanks in advance, please help me to resolve this issue.
```

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr Please check and let me know where am i doing different

Comment: 1) use GetResourceAsStream and avoid loaders, and pass this stream to load(). 2) Check if resource filtering is on. 3) read the javadoc for "available": "It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream"

Comment: Great, it worked great :) Thank you very much  @Tilman Hausherr for your Help :)

Comment: Great to hear that; please answer the question yourself, I don't know which hint(s) were the helping one(s). If it was the resource filtering, then delete your question, this has been answered before.

Comment: Hi@TilmanHausherr, the change i did is i removed the resLoader and added <<classname>>.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/the/file.pdf"). It worked without any issue. Thanks again :)